# Working with JSON.stringify( obj ) in node/express ejs

Tags: javascript, node.js, json, express, ejs

I'm trying to pass an object to my view using JSON.stringify but I am not sure how to access elements in the object. Here is how I pass the object to my view:

```
const getTracking = (request, response) => {
    pool.query('SELECT * FROM tracking', (error, results) => {
        if (error) {
            throw error
        }
        var trackingObj = JSON.stringify(results.rows);
        response.render('pages/trackingInfo', {
            trackingObj: trackingObj
        });
    })
}
```

Then in my index.ejs document I can access my object like so:

```
<p><%= trackingObj %></p>
```

which results in the following output in the browser (data is grabbed from postgres database):

```
[{"wo_num":1,"completion_date":"2021-08-04T04:00:00.000Z","material":"test","description":"test","qty":1,"total_hours":null},
{"wo_num":2,"completion_date":"2021-08-05T04:00:00.000Z","material":"test2","description":"test2","qty":2,"total_hours":2},
```

Is there a way to access the elements of this JSON.stringify object individually so I could do something like display them in a table?

Comment: simply remove JSON.stringify

Comment: If I remove JSON.stringify then the result shows up as [object Object],[object Object] @LawrenceCherone

Comment: That way you can access the object properties in template. Like displaying `trackingObj[0].material` would show you "test".

Comment: you can use JSON.parse to return the string to a json object

Answer (score 0):

```
 JSON.parse('<%- JSON.stringify(trackingObj) %>')
```

if you want to just see the content you can also use (will be displayed on the terminal

```
<% console.log(trackingObj) %>
```

for a better view :

```
<% console.table(trackingObj) %>
```

Answer (score 0):

As @Jayesh commented, the solution was to access the object using indices like so: `trackingObj[0].material`

To then display the elements in a table you can iterate through them in the following manner:

```
<% trackingObj.forEach(function(obj) { %>
<tr>
   <td> <%= obj.material %> </td>
   <td> <%= obj.wo_num %> </td>
<tr>
<% } %>
```